# How to send Control / in AHK

Tags: automation, autohotkey

I'm trying to send Control Forward Slash at one time in an AHK script.

I've tried:

Send ^{/}

Send ^/

Send {Ctrl Down}/{Ctrl Up}

I've also tried SendInput instead of just Send.

None  of them are working. I'm wanting to go to the search bar in the program my company uses but I can't get Control + Forward Slash to work

Comment: have you tried SendPlay?

Comment: Do you mean to the [`NumpadDiv` key](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#numpad)? At least my keyboard layout doesn't have the `/` key anywhere else without using a modifier, but maybe other keyboard layouts produce that key from somewhere else.

Comment: Agree it is some keyboard layout matter.  `^/` works for me. "`/`" (which is under the "`?`" next to "`Right-Shift`" on my standard US keyboard with separate extended number pad.

Answer (score 0):

Explain what you want to do and what should be accomplished by your code.
Are you asking how to send those characters to text, or how to emulate the pressing of those characters on your keyboard - like sending a hotkey?

`^/` works just like that as a hotkey trigger on my std US keyboard (the `/` being the unshifted `?` key).

If you are trying to send it as literal text, it is the control key `^` you have to escape.  So:

```
Send {^}/
```

would type it out as `^/`

Using `Send ^/` has the effect of whatever pressing `control-slash` is supposed to do.  For me, that's nothing special except in apps that map it to something.  If you want it as a hotkey and to refer to it in other parts of your code, give it a subroutine name as well, and just call it when needed.

```
my_subroutine:
^/::
    MsgBox Hello World
return

. . .

gosub my_subroutine
```